# How to sent different request using the same connection?

Tags: ios, http, nsurlconnection

My app behaves like this:

> **Client**: sent a request (using a `NSURLConnection`) to server asking server to generate a file and
>   download that file.
>
> **Server**: generate the file and send the file's data
>   back to client (using chunked encoding)
>
> *After generating the file, server will update the file's header, so after downloading
>   file, client needs to make second request to get the updated header. During
>   file generating and updating, if server detects that connection from client is
>   closed, it will delete the generated file, so the connection need to
>   be kept alive.*
>
> **Client**: sent a second request (another `NSURLConnection`) to get updated header

The problem is after first request (i use `NSURLConnection`) server detects connection closed and delete the generated file, so the second request fails.

I suspect the reason is that i use two different instance of `NSURLConnection`, so I look into the document for something like `NSMutableURLConnection`. It doesn't exist!.

My question: Is there a way to keep connection alive between to request ( by reusing `NSURLConnection`, or using `NSMutableRequest` and re-request with the same `NSURLConnection`)?

Comment: You're using asynchronous requests, right? Why not just use the connectionWithRequest:delegate: method a second time on the same instance

Comment: @Rohan connectionWithRequest:delegate: is a class method, it creates new instance of NSURLConnection. It meant it will create a new NSURLConnection object doesnt it?

Answer (score -1):

You can use :

```
NSURLConnection *currentConnection = [NSURLConnection alloc]; 
[currentConnection initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];

[currentConnection initWithRequest:request2 delegate:self];
```

You can verify the Original and Current NSURLRequest using :

```
- (NSURLRequest *)originalRequest NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (NSURLRequest *)currentRequest  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```